# Repackaging .jar-s in Android .aar library

Tags: java, android, package

#### Source Code

> [Library](https://bitbucket.org/victorapoyan/renamingpackagedependency)
>
> [Project which uses Library](https://bitbucket.org/victorapoyan/renamingpackagedependencyusage)

#### Problem Description

I'm writing Android Library (.aar) in that Library I'm using .jar libraries.

[image]

In order to avoid dependency duplication I'm using ShadowJar plugin for repackaging, as shown below:

```
task shadowJar(type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar) {
    System.out.println("Relocating packages...")
    relocate 'retrofit'               , 'com.codecraft.retrofit'
    relocate 'org.simpleframework.xml', 'com.codecraft.org.simpleframework.xml'
    relocate 'com.squareup.okhttp'    , 'com.codecraft.com.squareup.okhttp'
}
```

In the application which is using Android Library (.aar) I have dependency of shown below libraries, just for testing that I have no dependency duplication issues.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:2.0.0-beta1'
}
```

But when I try to run application on Android I got following error

[image]

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner
>   class Error:(com.bea.xml.stream.util.CircularQueue$1) that doesn't
>   come with an Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class
>   was probably produced by a Error:compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended Error:solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly Error:indicate that it is
>   *not* an inner class. Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class": Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of
>   a core class (java.* or javax.*) Error:when not building a core
>   library. Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core
>   library file Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE
>   (such as Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally
>   defining a Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation
>   of what's Error:going on. Error:However, you might actually be trying
>   to define a class in a core Error:namespace, the source of which you
>   may have taken, for example, Error:from a non-Android virtual machine
>   project. This will most Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it
>   jeopardizes the Error:compatibility of your app with future versions
>   of the platform. Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
>   Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
>   Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
>   Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>   Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
>   Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your
>   application Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point.
>   Please be Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example,
>   that your Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their
>   operating Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
>   Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
>   Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
>   Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
>   Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be
>   in Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may
>   help Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this,
>   then Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will
>   ultimately Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
>   Error:1 error; aborting :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

**PLEASE NOTE** that this issue didn't appear in the case if I add only retrofit dependency

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    }
```

**What is the reason and how I can solve this error?**

Comment: Pretty sure you can solve this by using `provided file("your.jar")` instead of using `compile`.

Comment: @JaredRummler that doesn't help, I still have same issue, maybe you can download my project and check yourself, maybe I am doing something wrong ? :(

Comment: Instead of packaging those jars in your library (which can lead to duplication in the using app), it is better not to package them but to tell Gradle that they will be provided. To do this, in the application building the aar, replace all "compile" keywords for dependencies to "provided". All apps using your library then also need to add those dependencies as a "compile" dependency. (Provided basically says: it's a runtime dependency, don't package it into my app)

Comment: @jmols the Idea behind my solution is that other apps which are using my library must NOT care about anything, they need just include my aar and use it's functionality and also be able to include same libraries or dependencies and have no conflict. That's why I want to rename package to avoid any kind of conflict.

Comment: The downsides are the your library will get bigger (method count), you will become responsible for upgrading all dependencies and you are hiding your dependencies from others. Also having multiple versions of the same library run in parallel can have serious side effects and will increase memory and threading footprint. I strongly advice against managing this yourself and rely on Gradle instead. Besides, adding an extra Gradle dependency should be straightforward for everyone, no?

Comment: @jmols I can agree with you, but what if anyway I want to do that? Because my question is how to rename package and use it ? The problems which can occurs while using package is something different.

Comment: Don't have any experience with that, I'm sorry...

Comment: @VictorApoyan Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

When you are including Jars in your lib or app - you may including files that have already been compiled using a different java version or with a different configuration than yours and this may cause problems like the one you are experiencing.

I guess the dependency you used refers to a library that does cause the problem that the jar creates.

If it's critical for you not to use dependencies - consider downloading the code for the lib you are using (assuming they are open source and there are no legal limitations) and compiling them with your app as additional modules in your project instead of adding the jar. If you do that - you should definitely consider what jmols wrote about the lib size and method count.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Exclude of some modules helped me with same error:

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
    exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
}
```

source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31762551/4929539)