# com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Multiple dex files define (...) BuildConfig

Tags: android, gradle

I've got a raw project using

```
compile            "com.library1:library1:2.0.4"
compile             "com.library2:library2:3.0.0"
```

whereas both library1:2.0.4 and library2:3.0.0 share the same namespace (have the same package names). Is there a clean way to let them coexist within one project without build time errors like:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define (...)/BuildConfig;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use different versions of the same library?

Comment: yes, but the migration has to be done over a longer period of time

Comment: Then deprecate the methods in the new versions and remove the old dependency

Comment: As written above I need to keep both libraries referred over a period of time. My code must compile and use both of them.

Comment: I'm not trying to disagree, just don't understand. According to semantic versioning, 2.3.0 isn't a major breaking change from 2.0.4

Comment: the libraries versions are 2.0.4 and 3.0.0...

Comment: My bad :) I saw `library2:3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow). I haven't used it, so I cannot give you more specific advice than pointing you to the [docs](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/), but I think that's the way to go, as some colleagues have told me that they've successfully used it for similar cases.

Notice that this process renames one of the libraries package name, and you will end up with something similar to:

- library1 -> com.library1
- library2 -> com.newlibrary1 (instead of com.library1 too)

So, if you rename the second library, at the end of the process (after removing old library) you will either have to disable the renaming of the second library and do a "Find in files" to change all the references to the renamed package; or leave the rename enabled forever. For me, first option will be the best.

See also this question [Repackaging .jar-s in Android .aar library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700083/repackaging-jar-s-in-android-aar-library), though I'm not sure if it's already outdated.

Comment: You can also exclude the group / artifact id from the dependencies

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, in other scenarios that would be a solution, but I understand that he's willing to migrate from one version to another gradually.

Comment: Just like the Android SDK, why not mark things as deprecated?

Comment: I understand that the libraries are 3rd party, plus the conflict will be there (old library and new one will share lots of duplicated classes).

Comment: looks like a solution, will give it a try and drop here my feedback

Comment: it fixes the issue